# Recover data from JQuery.post()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post

I'm using a `$.post()` to push data to a `php` file. But the `$_POST` is empty when I make a `var_dump` of it.

**`JS script`** :

```
 $('#Notes').on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let $id = $(document).getUrlParam("varname");
        let $text = $(this).attr('data');
        let $notes = prompt("Modifier la note", $text);
        console.log($text, $id, $notes);


        if ($notes !== null || $notes !== "") {
            $.post(
                '../buckets/update_note.buckets.php',
                {
                    id: $id,
                    notes: $notes,
                },
                function (data) {
                    console.log('Data Id : ',data.id);
                    console.log('Data Name : ',data.name);
                })
                .then(r =>{
                   location.replace('../buckets/update_note.buckets.php');
            })
         }
```

in **`php` file** :

```php
<?php

var_dump($_POST);
var_dump($_GET);
```

The 1st `console.log` in `js` show me the values of the 3 variables but the `console.log` in the callback show me `undefined`. But I see in the network debugger :

```
Form Data
id: xxxx
notes: xxxx
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe, data will be text in your case. You need to use `json_encode()` in you php to print complex objects. Then in your JS you can use `JSON.parse()` to restore object or define `application/json` content type in your `POST` query. Something like:

```js
// php
$json = json_encode([
  'post' => $_POST,
  'get'  => $_GET
]);

// js
function (response) {
  const data = JSON.parse(response);
}
```

Comment: Same issue I have echo the $json and the result is : '{"post":[],"get":[]}'

Answer (score 0):

You can try in this way.

JQuery CODE

```
$('#Notes').on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let $id = $(document).getUrlParam("varname");
        let $text = $(this).attr('data');
        let $notes = prompt("Modifier la note", $text);
        console.log($text, $id, $notes);
        if ($notes !== null || $notes !== "") {
            $.post(
                '../buckets/update_note.buckets.php',
                {
                    id: $id,
                    notes: $notes,
                },
                function (data) {
                var data=$.parseJSON(data);
                    console.log('Data Id : ',data.id);
                    console.log('Data Name : ',data.notes);
                })
                .then(r =>{
                   //location.replace('../buckets/update_note.buckets.php');
            })
         }
```

PHP CODE

```
  echo json_encode($_POST);
```

Comment: Same issue, the echo write [] on my php page, si it's empty.